# call next iteration in list after first comparision loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a situation where i have to loop over a list, grab info from a file, write a new file, send an email, and then go back to the list for the next iteration to start the process over again.
i'll try to write it out and then put my code in for you to look at.
the list is a list of ipaddresses and both files are text.

def grab info from a file1
def build my list1 (first code block)
def take list1[0] apply it to file1 and build file2 from it (second code block)
def get email address from list1[0]
def send email with file2
(i can do all of this, it's just getting back to list1[1] that i can't do)
go to list1[1] apply to file1 build file2 send email, etc... until end of list

```
  2 import re
  3 
  4 def one_ip_each():
  5     one_ip_each = []
  6     global ipAddr 
  7     with open('Invalid_names_file') as Invalid_names_file:
  8         a = [re.search(r'((\d+\.)+\d+)', line).group() for line in \
  9                 Invalid_names_file]
 10         for x in a:
 11             if x not in one_ip_each:
 12                 one_ip_each.append(x)
 13                 ipAddr = x
 14             return ipAddr
 15 ## makes an iterator that interpreter can step through, yet other funciton
 16 ## complains that it's not a string
 17 #        ipAddr = iter(one_ip_each)
 18 #        return ipAddr
 19 
 20 one_ip_each()
```

here's code that returns what i want (without ipAddr being an iter) and not looping)

```
  5 def isp_email_names():
  6     with open('Invalid_names_file') as Invalid_names_file:
  7         with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
  8             for line in Invalid_names_file:
  9                 if one_ip_each.ipAddr in line:
 10                     ISP_names_file.write(str(line))
 11                     ISP_names_file.flush()
```

hopefully with the line numbers this will help some.

i made the ipAddr a global so that i can call it from the email function to know that file2 is going to the proper people.
i don't know if this matters or not.

if i make the ipAddr into an iter (as line 17 and 18) i get ->

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list_iterator
```

i enjoy learning while i read, yet i'm stuck.  point me in the proper direction and i will read and come back to answer the question.
yet with what i have read people want to build filters, def more functions.

i would think that it should be pretty easy i just can't grasp it.
(post is kind of long, yet wanted to be thourough)

Comment: Format your code and text, or no one wants to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  0 def isp_email_names():
  1     with open('Invalid_names_file') as Invalid_names_file:
  2         with open('ISP_names_file', 'w') as ISP_names_file:
  3             for line in Invalid_names_file:
  4                 if one_ip_each.ipAddr in line:
```

Line 4， one_ip_each.ipAddr is a list_iter, line is a str.
String never contains list_iter.

You could try this:

```
if line in one_ip_each.ipAddr
```

Comment: thanks troy yet ipAddr is a substring of line, so that won't work.  looked at doing all(ipAddr in line for line in file) yet didn't get the output wanted.

Comment: i'm putting this on hold for now since it seems my testing machine is having problems that i have to pin down.  script is working on other machines, yet not the testing one.  thank you all.